# Remove / Hide Selected Item Title on Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I need to create a custom bottom navigation view. The case is when I click on any item, the label is gone and just show the icon. The example image is
[image: bottom nav example]

I'm trying to create a custom using selector like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tested"
        android:icon="@drawable/selector_nav_tested"
        android:title="tested"/>

</menu>
```

but it just change the icon. If I use `labelVisibilityMode = LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED`, the label is not shown on any navigation items. Is there any way to custom it by adding codes inside its `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` or do I need to use library ?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by default. You can override this by using

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

on your BottomNavigationView and it should force override it to show all the labels.

```
 app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"

 app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

The three above is the main points to keep.. Auto is the hiding when clicked.. labeled is always labeled, and unlabeled is no no labels.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The labelVisibilityMode attribute can be used to adjust the behavior of the [text](https://m2.material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#using-bottom-navigation) labels for each navigation item. There are four visibility modes:

**LABEL_VISIBILITY_AUTO** (default): The label behaves as “labeled” when there are 3 items or less, or “selected” when there are 4 items or more

**LABEL_VISIBILITY_SELECTED**: The label is only shown on the selected navigation item

**LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED**: The label is shown on all navigation items

**LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED**: The label is hidden for all navigation items

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
**app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"**
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Generate drawable for example tab_item_foreground.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
```

Then use like this.

```
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bnv_tab_item_foreground"
```

For icon's rounded corner background try this.

```
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/App.Custom.Indicator"
```

And style should be like this.

```
<style name="App.Custom.Indicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
    <item name="android:color">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:width">@dimen/_50dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/_50dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In each item of the menu.xml, remove the text from the titles and make them look like this:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tested"
        android:icon="@drawable/selector_nav_tested"
        android:title=""/>
```

Then in your layout, add a 16 dp top padding, this way it compensates for the reduced space of the text that does not exist.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:elevation="0dp" />
```